# Total row for SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following SQL query in SQL Server that returns the result shown below. However, I want to add a total row to my query result. In the total row, sold and opportunities should be SUMs, but the ratio should still be `SUM(sold) / SUM(opportunities)`. Not `SUM(ratio)`.

Desired output is also pictured below.

```sql
select 
    query1.date as 'Date', 
    Sold, Opportunities, 
    (Sold/Opportunities) as Ratio
from
    #query1 as query1
inner join 
    #query2 as query2 on query1.date = query2.date
order by 
    date;
```

Current output:

[image: Current Output]

Desired output:

[image: Desired Output]

Comment: Please provide example records for the temp tables #query1 and #query2

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Does this fiddle help you construct example records? https://dbfiddle.uk/HP6QXWZ4

Comment: Your "current output" looks like an Excel spreadsheet.  Is that what you have?  Because, of course, this would be trivial to do with two queries.

Comment: This is possible, but it's antithetical to relational set theory underpinning all databases. Rather, this is typically handled by the client code or reporting tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you want (have to double check the SUM query).

I have done stuff like this in the past.  What this does is run your normal query, and add the TOTAL query results using the UNION.  NOTE:  For UNION the number of columns and column names need to be the same that is why I don't have Total as column name in 2nd query.

I added the OrderBy column so you can make sure the normal data is displayed first BEFORE the total column.  Then it sorts by the date.

If you want the word TOTAL to be displayed where the date should be you can CAST the DATE in the first query as VARCHAR, and then instead of selecting DATE as NULL in 2nd query select 'TOTAL' as Date.  (you have to cast the date as VARCHAR because the UNION requires the data type to be the same (though the order by could get messed up).

```
SELECT 1 AS OrderBy, query1.date AS 'Date', Sold, Opportunities, (Sold/Opportunities) AS Ratio
FROM #query1 AS query1
INNER JOIN #query2 AS query2 ON query1.date = query2.date

UNION ALL

SELECT 2 AS OrderBy, NULL AS 'Date', SUM(Sold) AS Sold, SUM(Opportunities) AS Opportunities, (SUM(Sold)/SUM(Opportunities)) AS Ratio
FROM #query1 AS query1
INENR JOIN #query2 AS query2 ON query1.date = query2.date

ORDER BY OrderBy, date;
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use [`GROUP BY ROLLUP`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)? Much cleaner... For this you need to aggregate the values even if there is nothing to aggregate.

```
SELECT
    ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(12), q1.[Date], 103), 'Total') [Date]
    , SUM(sold) Sold
    , SUM(opportunities) Opportunities
    , CONVERT(decimal(9,2), SUM(sold) * 1.0 / SUM(opportunities) * 100.0) Ratio
FROM #query1 q1
JOIN #query2 q2 ON q1.[Date] = q2.[Date]
GROUP BY ROLLUP(q1.[Date]);
```

Note: Of course as said by everyone else, you would normally do this in your presentation layer. The database is for data, the presentation layer is for display.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between Excel and SQL. SQL is a Database. Excel is more of a visualization and aggregation tool. You would do this in a BI tool like PowerBI or alike, even SSRS... You can still do it, but wouldn't recommend doing it in SQL... but here you go

```
WITH agg AS ( 
        SELECT 'Total' as Date,
               SUM(Sold) as Sold,
               SUM(Opportunities) as Opportunities, 
               CONCAT(SUM(Sold)/SUM(Opportunities)*100, '%') as Ratio
        FROM original_tbl
   )
SELECT Date, 
       Sold, 
       CONCAT(Opportunities, ' (', Ratio, ')') as OpportunitiesAndRatio 
FROM agg 
UNION ALL
SELECT CAST(Date as STRING) as Date, 
       Sold, 
       CONCAT(CAST(Opportunities as STRING), ' (', CAST(Sold/Opportunities*100 as STRING), '%')  as Ratio
FROM original_tbl;
```

Answer (score 0):

I created temp tables and typed in values from your images. This allowed me to test the query. I created a total row using UNION with a query that summed the values. The Ratio is calculated as per your specifications.

```
CREATE TABLE #query1 (
  [date] date,
  sold int
)

CREATE TABLE #query2 (
  [date] date,
  Opportunities int
)
  

insert into  #query1  ([date] ,  sold)
values 
 ('1-1-2023',7)
,('2-1-2023',2)
,('3-1-2023',8)
,('4-1-2023',2)
,('5-1-2023',8)  
,('6-1-2023',6)
,('7-1-2023',3)
,('8-1-2023',3)
,('9-1-2023',6)
,('10-1-2023',3)
,('11-1-2023',5)
,('12-1-2023',3)

  
insert into  #query2  ([date] ,  Opportunities )
values 
 ('1-1-2023',15)
,('2-1-2023',6)
,('3-1-2023',13)
,('4-1-2023',14)
,('5-1-2023',14)  
,('6-1-2023',17)
,('7-1-2023',20)
,('8-1-2023',8)
,('9-1-2023',14)
,('10-1-2023',3)
,('11-1-2023',13)
,('12-1-2023',3)

 
select cast(#query1.[date] as varchar) as 'Date', Sold, Opportunities, 
     ( 
       CONCAT(
       cast( 
               cast(Sold as DECIMAL(5,1))
                /
               CAST(Opportunities as DECIMAL(5,1))
               *100
              as DECIMAL(5,1)
           )
           , '%')
     ) as Ratio 
  from #query1 
  inner join #query2 on #query1.[date] = #query2.[date] 
--order by [date];

UNION ALL
  
select 'TOTAL' as 'Date', sum(Sold) as sold, sum(Opportunities) as Opportunities, 
     ( 
       CONCAT ( 
       cast( 
               cast(sum(Sold) as DECIMAL(5,1))
                /
               CAST(sum(Opportunities) as DECIMAL(5,1))
               *100
              as DECIMAL(5,1)

           )
                , '%')
     ) as Ratio 
  from #query1 
  inner join #query2  on #query1.[date] = #query2.[date]
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ONSaXCA2)

| Date | Sold | Opportunities | Ratio |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 7 | 15 | 46.7% |
| 2023-02-01 | 2 | 6 | 33.3% |
| 2023-03-01 | 8 | 13 | 61.5% |
| 2023-04-01 | 2 | 14 | 14.3% |
| 2023-05-01 | 8 | 14 | 57.1% |
| 2023-06-01 | 6 | 17 | 35.3% |
| 2023-07-01 | 3 | 20 | 15.0% |
| 2023-08-01 | 3 | 8 | 37.5% |
| 2023-09-01 | 6 | 14 | 42.9% |
| 2023-10-01 | 3 | 3 | 100.0% |
| 2023-11-01 | 5 | 13 | 38.5% |
| 2023-12-01 | 3 | 3 | 66.7% |
| TOTAL | 56 | 140 | 39.3% |